# Flatten the Data dynamically

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, javascript-controller

I need to flatten my SObject data dynamically based on another list.
`fieldToDisplayList` contains list of fields to display, which I want to flatten.
Using below syntax I'm able to flatten the data but it's hard-coded, which I want to avoid:

```js
return{
    ...row, 
    companyName: row.rec[fieldToDisplayList[0]], 
    companyId: row.rec[fieldToDisplayList[1]]
}
```

**JS Code:**

```js
flatData = flatData.map((row, index)=>{
    var flattenSObjectData;
    for(var j = 0; j < fieldToDisplayList.length; j++) {
        flattenSObjectData = [];
        // this is not returning any value
        console.log('>>> fieldToDisplayList values... ', fieldToDisplayList[j]); 
    }
                                    
    // This works fine, instead of hardcoding values here want to do it using for 
    // loop, but in console log I'm not getting any value
    return{
        ...row, 
        companyName: row.rec[fieldToDisplayList[0]], 
        companyId: row.rec[fieldToDisplayList[1]]
    }
});
```

Comment: `+fieldToDisplayList[j]` tries to convert the contents to a number (because it follows `,`, which makes it a separate parameter to console.log). I presume this isn't what you meant to do.

Comment: Yes, that's mistake, but how do I iterate it to flatten

Comment: How do you know where companyName is supposed to come from? You can do this dynamically, but you need a way to map the values together.

Comment: Well instead of CompanyName, I created an attribute based on a combination of object and it's field API name, to make it unique. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue:

```
flatData = flatData.map((row, index)=>{
                                var flattenSObjectData = {};
                                for(var j =0; j < fieldToDisplayList.length; j++){
                                    let labelName = this.DefaultObject + fieldToDisplayList[j];
                                    flattenSObjectData[labelName] = row.rec[fieldToDisplayList[j]];
                                    //flattenSObjectData.push({companyName : row.rec[fieldToDisplayList[j]]});
                                    console.log('>>> fieldToDisplayList values... '+fieldToDisplayList[j]);
                                }
                                console.log('>>> flattenSObjectData... '+JSON.stringify(flattenSObjectData));
                                
                                //return{...row, Company__cName: row.rec[fieldToDisplayList[0]], Company__cId: row.rec[fieldToDisplayList[1]]}
                                return{...row, ...flattenSObjectData}
                            });
```